# Развертывание node.js приложения

Tags: node.js, angular2, iis, развертывание, build

Есть приложение - клиент на Angular4, сервер на node.js. Развертываю приложение в локальной сети на IIS. Клиента успешно удалось разместить, а как разместить сервер на node.js - без понятия. Что нужно для билда самого приложения и дальнейшего размещение на IIS, при том чтобы можно было взаимодействовать с клиентом

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, не могу добавить комментарий к первому ответу, но обязательно надо использовать npm-пакет **pm2**(linux) или **forever**(windows) (это альтернативный запуск вместо 4-го пункта).
Необходимость использования объясняется просто: если запускать просто командой *node*, то при любом необработанном исключении сервер просто отрубится и выдаст ошибку в консоль. pm2 же ошибку запишет в файлик, а сервер мгновенно перезапустит.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то:

1. На сервере, паралельно IIS надо установить [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/);
2. Скопируй код твоего приложения на сервер, допустим, в директорию `c:\Node`;
3. Запусти коммандную консоль;
4. Допустим, главный исполняемый файл называется **index.js**, в таком случае, что-бы запустить твоё приложение, тебе надо выполнить комманду `node c:\Node\index.js`

Что-бы клиент мог общатся с сервисами на Node.js, на IIS надо настроить переброс (проксирование) запросов, подробное описание можно найти здесь: https://adamtuttle.codes/add-node-to-existing-iis-server/

Что-бы твоё Node.js приложение запускалось как сервис Windows, можно использовать [node-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/node-windows)